# sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, base64

while trying encryption I came across with this in GAE
"sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment"

can any one help on which package I should use?
I'm trying to get AES encryption.
here is code that I'm using.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


import sun.misc.*;

public class AESencrp {
private static final String ALGO = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue = 
    new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't','S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
    return key;
}



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/). There is a class [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) that provides Base64 encoding and decoding.

`sun.*` packages are not part of the supported, public interface. Check out this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) for more details.

Comment: This is what I got--The import org.apache.commons cannot be resolved

Comment: I am not able to find suitable replacement for 
yte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);

Can you suggest some method in commons Codec for the method decodeBuffer ??

Comment: @bali208 did you try [decodeBase64()](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28byte[]%29) ?

Comment: Guava now also has Base64 (as of v14).